# Problem with LaTeX (Texmaker produces nothing)

Tags: compiling

I got this problem when I run my code:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdftex' has already been used,
(hyperref) setting the option has no effect on input line 75.
```

Comment: Well, the `Taxmaker` is not supposed to produce PDF from latex ;-) For TeXMaker we need more information on your document ...

Comment: we need a minimal example of your code that produce the problem

Comment: Read the line 75 of your source code and think about it...

Comment: This is just an innocuous warning and should have no impact on the final result. Some more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you say Texmaker produces nothing, do you mean nothing appears in the pane on the right hand side of Texmaker, or do you mean no PDF is produced in the folder which contains your latex document?

If you have a PDF of your document in your folder but not appearing in the Texmaker pane, you just have to click the 'View PDF' arrow which is up the top next to the button you pressed to Latex the document.

If you have no PDF in your folder then you need to determine what the error is (as already said, it's not the hyperref warning). You should have a file in your folder which has the same name as your latex document but which ends in .log. Have a look at that to determine the real error.